# Understanding Rolling Windows in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the 6th element value. as true but get NaN instead. I have an example based out of Excel. When i try rolling window of 6, i get nan for 6th record but i should get False, instead. However, when i try rolling window of 5, all seems to work. I want to understand what is actually happened and what is the best way to say sum product of 6 elements means rolling window of 6 instead of 5.

[image]

Objective :  Six points in a row, all increasing or all decreasing

Code I am trying

```
def condition(x):
             if x.tolist()[-1] != 0:
                 if ( sum(x.tolist()) >= 5 or sum(x.tolist()) <= -5):
                     return 1
                 else:
                     return 0
             else:
                 return 0

df_in['I GET'] = df_in[['lead_one']].rolling(
            window=6).apply(condition  , raw=False)
```

> Tag column is what is expected.

Comment: Hi Saqib, if you like my answer you please upvote and accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a rolling window of 6, it takes the current value + the previous 5 values. Then you try to sum those 6 values. I say try, because if there's any nan value in there, ordinary python summing will also give you an na value.
That's also why .rolling(window=5) works: it gets the current value + 4 previous values and since they don't contain any nan values, you actually get a summed value one row earlier

You could use a different kind of summing: `np.nansum()`
Or use pandas summing where you specify to skip the na's, something like: `df['column'].sum(skipna=True)`

However looking at your code, I think it could be improved, so you don't get the na's in the first place. Here's an example using `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 10, 9],
    columns=['value']
)

# create an if/then using np.select
df['n > n+1'] = np.select(
    [df['value'] >  df['value'].shift(1),
     df['value'] == df['value'].shift(1),
     df['value'] < df['value'].shift(1)],
    [1, 0, -1]
)

# take an absolute value of the last 6 values and check if >= 5
df['I GET'] = np.where(
    np.abs(df['n > n+1'].rolling(window=6).sum()) >= 5, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Sander, but i think issue was that window=5 means 1+5 away from the current position and that's the reason, 5 was working in my case. Also. i have tried `np.nansum` aswell to get this working for me. I will post my answer soon.